# Redirecting subdomain URL to specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

On my site, each group has a specific URL, eg: domain.com/my-group, domain.com/my-group2 and so on..

What I would like is that the user uses my-group.domain.com, my-group2.domain.com to get to its group.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Apache to listen on both  my-group.domain.com and my-group2.domain.com using the Virtual Host configuration.

Apache's documentation on this topic should be enough to get you started:
 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/